# Last Docker Desktop for Windows installation crash

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am trying to install the last version of Docker for Windows from this link https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

The installation always crash with the following error:

> Unable to
>   check availability for Windows feature *Hyper-V*: Le fichier spécifié
>   est introuvable.
>
> à Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[]
>   parameters) dans
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:ligne
>   36    à Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean
>   showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) dans
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:ligne
>   92    à Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.b__0()
>   dans
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:ligne
>   155    à Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() dans
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:ligne 59

This might be because I don't have Hyper V on my computer but It should allow me to install it with **Docker Desktop for Windows**.
My operating system is **Windows 10 Pro 64 bits**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually activate Hyper-V. In order to do that I had to:

1. Resolve Windows update issues with Microsoft [wu10.diagcab](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter) tool, launched in administrator mode
2. Activate Hyper-V with the following command, in a Powershell launched in administrator mode: `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`

Comment: Glad you resolved it.  For any others who have a similar problem, sometimes you also need to drop into the BIOS of your computer and enable Hyper-V in there first.